docker compose up suddenly giving permission errors on springboot and nextjs application
Whenever i used to run docker compose up it would start the container for springboot and nextjs application and everything would work fine. I ran docker compose down after which i ran docker compose up and everything started to break, i would get this error:
nextjs      | exec ./run.sh: permission denied
springboot  | Error: Unable to access jarfile build/libs/project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
springboot exited with code 1
nextjs exited with code 1

Here are the important parts of docker files:

docker compose

services:
  backend:
    container_name: springboot
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./backend
        target: /app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true

  frontend:
    container_name: nextjs
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./frontend
        target: /app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    stdin_open: true


main docker file

# Build the backend
WORKDIR /app/backend
COPY ./backend/src/main/resources/application.yml application.yml
RUN ./gradlew bootJar && cp ./build/libs/*.jar app.jar

# Build the frontend
WORKDIR /app/frontend
RUN npm install && npm run build


backend docker file

FROM gradle:jdk21-jammy

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "build/libs/project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar", "--spring.profiles.active=dev"]


frontend docker file

FROM node:21

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"]

Here's some of the linked file important parts:

application.yml

spring:
  application:
    name: project


build.gradle.kts

version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

I was expecting docker compose up to work normally and start containers like it used to.
I also tried to chmod +x run.sh the run.sh file outside my container after which i stopped getting the nextjs | exec ./run.sh: permission denied error but docker compose up would give more permission errors down the line. I also tried to rebuild everything from scratch, removing all containers, caches everything but the problem persists.

Your frontend image doesn't seem to contain the run.sh script, or anything at all other than the Node interpreter.  Are you missing a COPY command there?  It looks like you're replacing most of the contents of both images with Docker bind mounts, which can result in non-reproducible behavior that depends on what's on the host system; does deleting the volumes: blocks in the Compose file make any difference?
